# Why is the integer size limit different on Rails when using PostgreSQL v. MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm migrating my app from MySQL to Postgres. If I do a `rake db:schema:load`, it loads fine into Postgres, and all my tests pass.

If I do `rake db:migrate:reset`, then an integer column that I had previously set to have `:limit => 1` is set to have `:limit => 2`.

My migration sets it like so:

```
t.integer "foo", :limit => 1, :null => false
```

Is it simply a matter of Postgres having a lower minimum size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`smallint` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) in PostgreSQL occupies two byte and accepts numbers from -32768 to +32767.

There is no [`tinyint` like in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html) that occupies 1 byte and accepts numbers from -128 to 127.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres doesn't provide a 1-byte integer type. The smallest datatype for integer is the 2-byte smallint.